# Secure USB flash drives that don't require a reboot

Tags: windows, encryption, usb-flash-drive, security

As a result of data loss, we now have a corporate policy (imposed by a major partner as a condition of continued funding, so non-negotiable) that only approved storage devices can copy data from our network - basically, only external HDDs and Flash drives that use encryption.

The problem comes when users take their flash drives off-site with a Powerpoint presentation on and plug it into a someone else's PC. The drives want to install software (some require admin rights) and reboot in order to work, which causes all sorts of problems.

**Can anyone suggest a secure/encrypted USB flash drive that connects to PCs with the minimum of fuss?**

Let's limit it to Windows, since bringing OSX and Linux into the mix makes it even harder.

Answer (score 5):

Do ironkey USB drives require special drivers? https://www.ironkey.com/

Edit: nope. From [the FAQ](https://learn.ironkey.com/faqs#disp), it doesn't require special software or drivers, apparently. Nor admin rights.

Comment: I'll look into them, thanks. If they turn out to work, I'll come back and accept this as an answer. Anyone on SF actually used them in the context of my question?

Answer (score 2):

You've just discovered the 'killer app' reason to upgrade all the desktop operating systems in your organization to Windows 7 !

*cheers*

It's called [BitLocker To Go](http://www.microsoft.com/downLoads/details.aspx?familyid=6E419E75-BBEC-44BF-BF94-48EC4E1265AC&displaylang=en)

It may not make sense right now, but it's definitely the way of the future & means that you can centalize management & not require any special hardware storage.

Comment: As long as everyone you interact with is using Windows 7... :-) (entered using FireFox for Linux...)

Comment: not quite.  as long as the files are encrypted in windows 7 which has bitlocker to go, the can be decrypted on Vista & XP

Comment: Whereas truecrypt works on Linux, OS X and Windows 7/xp/2000/vista/<server editions>...

Comment: wow, truecrypt looks cool. Howcome its not in your answer?

Comment: Very interesting, but obviously a solution for several years in the future, rather than now. I'll keep an eye on it.